# alert in embedded webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

When embedding WebView in an application and loading html-pages in it, JavaScripts alert() do not work.Give me an example pls

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default `WebChromeClient` implemented by the embedded browser will discard javascript alerts, you should override the `WebChromeClient` implementation with your own version, this also allows you the ability to create your own custom alerts in place of the default one like so:

```
browser.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

...

```
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }
}
```