# Pause page processing in an Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I recently set up alerts in a WebView using the info here: [alert in embedded webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979291/alert-in-embedded-webview)

However, I noticed that the page continues to load behind the alert. This is particularly dangerous when it comes to javascript confirm dialogs.

How can I pause the page loading until the alert is dismissed?